# Targetting chrome profile in selenium

Tags: selenium

Trying to run selenium script with targeted chrome profile. But once I run the script, it won't start with the targeted profile but with a new profile. Here's my code:

```
# import selenium common driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# for specified chrome profile
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# wait page until targeted element loaded
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# undetectable module
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc # use pip install undetected-chromedriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()

    # another way to set profile is the below (which takes precedence if both variants are used
    options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Fadli\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 4')

    # just some options passing in to skip annoying popups
    options.add_argument(r'--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)  # version_main allows to specify your chrome version instead of following chrome global version

    driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below line if it help

```
# another way to set profile is the below (which takes precedence if both variants are used
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Fadli\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 4')
```

[you can check it here for more reference](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md)

Answer (score 0):

For people looking to target a specific chome profile with the **undetected chromedriver library**, all you need to do is this:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, executable_path="data/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

In the documentation it's written this way:

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.user_data_dir = "c:\\temp\\profile"
```

Both methods should work
https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/