# How to load custom profile in Chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to launch custom profile in chrome using python selenium webdriver.
But I met error while running. I tried arguments --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --remote-debugging-port=xxxx. But not working.

Here is code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 6")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/SIM/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
time.sleep(3)
```

Here is output.

```
D:\me\web\fbot\src>python script_.py
Opening in existing browser session.
[7488:16428:1223/013230.522:ERROR:broker_win.cc(56)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\me\web\fbot\src\script_.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__      
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__   
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__     
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x0103F243]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC7FD1]
        (No symbol) [0x00EBD04D]
        (No symbol) [0x00EDC24E]
        (No symbol) [0x00ED82E9]
        (No symbol) [0x00F0F056]
        (No symbol) [0x00F0EB2A]
        (No symbol) [0x00F08386]
        (No symbol) [0x00EE163C]
        (No symbol) [0x00EE269D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012D9A22+2655074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012CCA24+2601828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010E8C0A+619850]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010E7830+614768]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD05FC]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD5968]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD5A55]
        (No symbol) [0x00FE051B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7762FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CD7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CD7A4E+238]
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Before executing the code, close all the chrome browser windows then try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72077446/5151769 check this if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume your profile path is wrong,
try adding this command to your driver class:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/alexiseggermont/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/")
```

This path is usable for Mac or Linux OS. Also, rename "Default" to your profile id (for me, and in most cases, it was "Profile 1")

Comment: Yes, Default profile works. but I want to load profile 6. It is exist in my directory. But when I try to load custom profile, these error are raising.